# Jquery post with umlauts

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I read about the special characters and umlauts in javascript is a bit tricky and I couldn't find the right answer for my problem.

For example:

```
                $.post('test.php','club=Fc Köln', 
                    function(response){ 
                        /*--- do something from database with response---*/
                        }
                });
```

If I send a club name like Fc Köln or Deportiva la coruña javascript can't handle it, does someone have the right solution?

Regards,

Frank

Comment: Did you try sending them as Unicode or HTML entities?

Comment: This seems more like a problem in your file encoding. Is it utf-8 ? try with another editor.

Comment: Have you tried using `escape()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try using `encodeURIComponent`[<sup>DOCS</sup>](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp):

```
$.post('test.php', encodeURIComponent('club=Fc Köln'), 
  function(response){ 
    /*--- do something from database with response---*/
  }
});
```

And on the php side you could use `urldecode()`[<sup>DOCS</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) if need be to get your characters back in their original form.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure your text file is encoded in UTF_8 or something like that.

If you use Notepad++ you can easily check and change the encoding of your text files.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post('test.php',escape(clubName), 
    function(response){ 
       /*--- do something from database with response---*/
    }
});
```

Use [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) to decode on the server side.